# Within Python Pandas, how to compare different rows in one dataframe without using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I am trying to have Python Pandas calculate a value based on the value in a cell in the current row and a cell in the previous row. I have the following simplified dataframe in which i am trying to calculate the time between the current estimated arrival time and the landing time of the previous aircraft. I have a flight schedule which I convert to the datetime format.

```
import pandas as pd

f = {'Estimated_Arrival_Time': pd.Series(['08:09', '08:39', '08:50']),
      'Landing_Time': pd.Series(['08:10', '08:45', '09:10'])}
Flight_df = pd.DataFrame(f)

Flight_df.loc[:,'Estimated_Arrival_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Flight_df.loc[:,'Estimated_Arrival_Time'],format='%H:%M')
Flight_df.loc[:,'Landing_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Flight_df.loc[:,'Landing_Time'],format='%H:%M')
```

Right now, i have solved the comparison by writing a for loop. However, i am wondering if it possible to code this without using a for-loop but by exploiting the properties of pandas and dataframes.

```
for i in xrange(len(Flight_df)):
    if i == 0:
        Flight_df.loc[i,'Inter_arrival_time'] = pd.Timedelta(0,'s')
    else:
        Flight_df.loc[i,'Inter_arrival_time'] = Flight_df.at[ i,'Estimated_Arrival_Time'] - Flight_df.at[(i-1),'Landing_Time']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shift operation and fill the NaN later with 0
`Flight_df['Estimated_Arrival_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Flight_df['Estimated_Arrival_Time'])`

```
Flight_df['Inter_arrival_time'] = Flight_df.Estimated_Arrival_Time - Flight_df.Estimated_Arrival_Time.shift(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want `pd.Series.shift()`:

```
Flight_df['Inter_arrival_time'] = Flight_df['Estimated_Arrival_Time'] - Flight_df['Landing_Time'].shift()
```

Output:

```
0        NaT
1   00:29:00
2   00:05:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```